# Open Huge XML files and Pretty-Print

Tags: xml, editor

I need to view XML files, each of 3-4 GB.

Could anybody tell me best free tool/trial version to view huge size XML because if I open it in some editor, its giving me "Out of memory"? I need the pretty-print option as well in it. I tried `010 Editor` but it doesn't have pretty-print option in it.

Answer (score 17):

pretty print xml using xmllint command:

xmllint --format xml_file.xml > pretty_xml_file.xml

and now you can open pretty_xml_file.xml in vi or your favorite editor

Comment: Good suggestion. You might consider giving the OP the subprocess call code so that it's explicit that xmllint is not a python module.

Comment: Might need to include the `--stream` arg since the OP says the input XML files are 3-4GB. Not positive though.

Comment: for huge files, you have to add --huge

Comment: For a almost-single-line 600MB XML file `xmllint` writes a 0 byte output file with both `--stream` and `--huge`. Exit code is 0 though :(

Comment: I have a 4 GiB XML-file and no matter which switches are used, the output is pretty much the same as input.